# Can't build with 5.3.0.GA on Windows: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I get the error below when I try to build for device or simulator within Appcelerator Studio - target is Android.

I've tried reinstalling Appcelerator + studio multiple times but nothing helps.
This is only an isssue with the new 5.3.0.GA SDK.

**Anyone know what's going on? It works fine on my Mac.**

Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.6.0.201605201934

Build: jenkins-appcelerator-rcp-master-353 (origin/master)
Date: 20 May 2016, 19:35:22

Windows 11

```
2016-06-08T07:19:23.875Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1465367918028
2016-06-08T07:19:24.156Z | TRACE  | No project alloy hook; skipping update to 1.0.0
2016-06-08T07:19:26.203Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
2016-06-08T07:19:26.204Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
2016-06-08T07:19:26.205Z | TRACE  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.3.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\titanium.js:65:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at set (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.3.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\titanium.js:64:24)
at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.3.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\titanium.js:100:6
at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.3.0.GA\mobileweb\cli\commands\_build.js:105:4
at CLI._fireHookCallback (c:\Users\Dan\.appcelerator\install\5.3.0\package\node_modules\titanium\lib\hook.js:267:3)
at c:\Users\Dan\.appcelerator\install\5.3.0\package\node_modules\titanium\lib\hook.js:248:10
at c:\Users\Dan\.appcelerator\install\5.3.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:697:13
at c:\Users\Dan\.appcelerator\install\5.3.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
at c:\Users\Dan\.appcelerator\install\5.3.0\package\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:267:21
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this myself, by editing 3 js files within the 5.3.0.GA SDK dir (also created a JIRA issue, so hopefully this will be fixed soon).

Looks like it has to do with not having Visual Studio and/or Windows SDK installed.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3803

Files to edit:
mobilesdk\win32\5.3.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\titanium.js: https://www.diffchecker.com/owvwlbd3
mobilesdk\win32\5.3.0.GA\windows\cli\commands_build\config\vstarget.js: https://www.diffchecker.com/r2wgxkew
mobilesdk\win32\5.3.0.GA\windows\cli\commands_build\config\wpSDK.js: https://www.diffchecker.com/zdvf9qyn

Answer (score 0):

The bug you have mentioned is found to be occurring on systems where Visual Studio is not installed. It is already addressed and Appcelerator engineering team is onto it (As described in JIRA). I hope that it will be fixed very soon. Meanwhile you can build app using SDK 5.2.2.GA.
You can see issue update here : [JIRA TICKET](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23484)